# asp.net MVC the microsoft edit template not including displaying object data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I used the edit template view for visual studio and it creates a nice form for me. The problem is that none of the objects data is included in the form. for example see this code this section:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoDesc) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.VideoDesc) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoDesc) %>
    </div>
```

On the server side I have the following:

```
    public ActionResult editvid(int id)
    {
        using (VideoDBEntities ent = new VideoDBEntities())
        {
            var vids = from myRow in ent.Videos
                        where (myRow.VideoId == id)
                       select myRow;

             ViewData["model"] =  vids.ToList()[0];
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I am new to MVC and LINQ and trying to find my feet

thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a strongly typed view you can pass your video object as model.
It is done by sending it as a parameter in `View()` method.

[View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view.aspx) can be overloaded with model object, if you have no model you can leave it empty.

in this case you can simply define `video` variable and pass it to the `View`.

```
using (VideoDBEntities ent = new VideoDBEntities())
{
       var video = ent.Videos.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.VideoId ==id);
       return View(video );
}
```